# How to show User notification twice on single button click using NSUserNotification?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Let me first describe the scenario then I will describe the issue:

I have created a function that shows a user notification using NSUserNotification

```
    -(void)notify:(NSString*) message {

    NSUserNotification *notification = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init];
    notification.title = @"TechHeal";
    notification.informativeText = message;
    //notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName;

    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:notification];    
}
```

I have a button the fetches details from the server. At the begening and at the end of the button click I have called the notification as shown below:

```
-(IBAction)get2000Rows:(id)sender{

    [self notify:@"Please wait..."];

    //some code that takes a while to run. like 10 minues :P

    [self notify:@"Thanks for waiting..."];

}
```

Now, the issue is that the first notification "Please wait..." is not getting shown on the button click however the last notification is showing perfectly.

I also tried to call Notify function in a seprate thread but it did not worked as well. (Shown Below)

```
dispatch_queue_t backgroundQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.mycompany.myqueue", 0);

    dispatch_async(backgroundQueue, ^{

        [self notify:@"Please wait..."];


        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        });    
    });
```

Your help is really appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Try showing the alert in a new thread

Comment: I wish i could but I have to show a user Notification and I also used a new thread but nothing seems to be working that's why I have posted this question  @lulian Onofrei

Comment: Please post the code of the failed attempt to run in a new thread as an edit to this question

Comment: @lulian Onofrei Sir, I have updated the question you may check. Thank you for showing interest in my problem.

Comment: Wait, I think that what I said is stupid, the UI part has to run on the main thread, so try [this code](http://pastebin.com/yLvG7Mv5)

Comment: @Lulian Onofrei sir.. has anyone ever.. ever told you that you are awesome. Thanks a ton. Please post it as answer so that other may also have benefit of your intelligence.

Comment: Thank you for the generous compliments! I'm glad it helped you. I posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you run your `10 minutes` code on the same thread as the `UI` part of the code. So you should separate those using this:

```
-(IBAction)get2000Rows:(id)sender{

    [self notify:@"Please wait..."];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        //some code that takes a while to run. like 10 minues :P

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void) {
            [self notify:@"Thanks for waiting..."];
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can start the timer through `NSTimer` for remessage

```
@interface MyClass ()
{
     NSTimer *timer;
}

-(IBAction)get2000Rows:(id)sender{

       [self notify:@"Please wait..."];


       timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0f
                                                target:self
                                            selector:@selector(timerClick:)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                             repeats:YES];
}

 - (void)timerClick:(NSTimer *)timer {

        [self notify:@"Thanks for waiting..."];
 }
```

Comment: I tried this code in my application and its not working. The
Result was: 1. all data got fetched 2. notification shown "Please wait.." 3. notification shown "thanks for waiting".

Comment: what you want then? you want message after 10 min like .then after 10 min  `timerClick` fired

Comment: Actually, I did know want the message after 10 minutes (it was an example). what I wanted is to show a notification before server request and a notification after server request.  here is the answer:  [link](http://pastebin.com/yLvG7Mv5)
Thank you @Mayank